# Can a Bouyant bottle in water lift an identical bottle full of water outside of water

Tags: gravity, pressure, air

Imagine you have 2, 5 Litre bottles.

One of them is full of air at normal air pressure and is submerged at the bottom of a 5m tube full of water.

The submerged bottle has a piece of string hanging from the bottom of it, and it goes out of the bottom of the 5m tube (For arguements sake, lets say this is frictionless and doesn't leak)

At the bottom of the string is another 5Litre bottle full of water.

What would happen? Would the water bottle full of water pull the bottle full of air down? Vice versa? or would it be a perfect equalibrium?

Comment: If question asks what happens when different forces act on a body try Newton’s Second Law. For simplicity, the forces acting on a bottle full of water are it’s weight and string tension. String tension is equal to net force acting on bottle full of air (mainly buoyant force, so Archimedes principle looks helpful in this case)

Comment: PS don’t forget, that buoyancy acts on water bottle too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case further explanation is needed, here is how to solve such problems:

Consider a cubical region submerged in water (or any other fluid):
[image]

We will denote:

- H as height of the container
- $h_1$ as height from top of the container to the upper surface of cube
- $h_2$ as height from the top container to the bottom surface of cube
- $\rho_{fluid}$ as density of the fluid

Then the derivation is as follows:
There are pressures acting on the cube.
To calculate them, we start with basic definition: $p=\frac FA$, where the left side is pressure and right side is force divided by area.

Since we are interested in pressures acting on a cube, let $A$ be the area of a cube. The force acting on a cube is weight of the column of water acting above it.

Thus:
$p=\frac {mg}{A} = \frac{\rho_{fluid}*V*g}{A}$

(*note that $V$ is simply $A*h$*)

Therefore if we denote $p_1$ as pressure acting on top of the surface and $p_2$ as pressure acting on the bottom surface of the cube and noting that other sides of the cube produce no pressure difference, as the fluid level is at the same height, we have:
$$p_1=\rho_{fluid}*g*h_1,\space\space p_2=\rho_{fluid}*g*h_2\\\implies\\\Delta p = p_2 - p_1 = \rho_{fluid}*g*(h_2-h_1)$$

As mentioned in the comment if we are interested in what will happen to the objects if forces act on it, we want to calculate forces in the first place.

By using the same equation, $F=p*A$ To calculate buoyancy we are interested in difference of forces acting on top and bottom of the cube.

Thus:
$$F_{buoyant}=A*\Delta p=\rho_{fluid}*g*(V_2-V_1)$$

Noting that $V_2-V_1$ is simply a volume of our object, we have:

$F_{buoyant}=\rho_{fluid}*g*V_{object}$

Now here comes the solution to your problem:

As mentioned in the comments, the forces acting on your water bottle are:

- it's weight
- buoyant force
- string tension

The string tension is buoyancy of bottle with air in it (I think we can safely ignore it's weight in this case).

Therefore forces acting on our bottle with water are:
$$F_{net}=F_{buoyancy}+F_{string}-F_{weight}=[\rho_{fluid}*g*V_{object}]+[\rho_{fluid}*g*V_{object}]+[-mg]$$

Noting that $m = \rho_{fluid}*V_{object}$

We get:
$$F_{net}=F_{buoyancy}$$

You can think of this result such that the weight of water bottle gets 'cancelled' with its buoyancy. The remaining force from string tension is equal to buoyancy of the bottle with air in it.

In short: The bottle with water will move according to Newton's Second Law with net force equal to buoyancy of bottle containing air.